# Email and Messaging difficulties

Tags: mail.app, messages

I'm struggling to log out of iMessages and Mail. iMessages has no *Preferences* tab as everyone has said. How can I log out of both?

Comment: You didn't tell us whether you mean on phone or Mac

Answer (score 1):

Preferences tab is on the name of iMessage and Mail. On top, it says mail in bolder text, there is preferences in there. The shortcut to preferences tab is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> There you can log out. In preferences, click Accounts. There you can add or delete accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The Preferences "tab" - actually window - is accessible from the Mac's menu bar. Just to the right of the Apple icon in the upper left, click the program name (Mail or Messages) and then click Preferences. You can also use the keyboard, with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>.

You can log out through the Preferences window, or you can go to System Preferences, click on Internet Accounts (third row down) and then log out from there.